# Why the first request to video server did not return bytes data of the video

Tags: http, go, video

I wrote a simple video server as follow:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    video, err := os.Open("/Users/icheer/Downloads/jsc/jsc.mp4")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer video.Close()

    http.ServeContent(w, r, "jsc.mp4", time.Now(), video)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", ServeHTTP)
    _ = http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

It works well, but I am curious about what chrome do when I open http://localhost:8080 in chrome.

[image]

Why the first request status code is `200`, but the '`Tim`e' is '`Pending`', what '`Pending`' exactly mean? How did chrome know the request show '`Pending`'? And what confused me most is, i do not know which line of my golang code result in that. As the source code `net/http/fs.go` shows,

[image]

the `sendSize` is the total length of the video 5357093240, so I think the first request should return all bytes data of the video , but in fact, the response Size is 177B as the first picture shows, I do not know which line of the golang code result in that.

Comment: Check the request details, it's probably a `HEAD` or `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: it is a 'GET'...